# Как изменить шрифт в messagebox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, messagebox

в меню вызываю диалоговое окно с информацией, так как текста много нужно изменить размер шрифта.
подскажите как это можно реализовать (если можно)

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
 
root = Tk()

def o_prog():
        
        info = '''
                \"****************\"
                Язык разработки:    Python 3.8
                Используемые модули и библиотеки:
                - tkinter
                - datetime
                - time
                - locale
                - ttk.tkinter

                Дата выхода:
                Version_0.0.1:     07. 2020
                ***********
               *********************
                     '''
        mb.showinfo ("О программе", info)
o_prog()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Хотел предложить вариант с `option_add` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39183159/5909792), но он не работает потому что последнии версии tk используют нативные диалоговые окна (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53705264/5909792) :) Как вариант, можно сделать свой диалог: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm

Comment: @gil9red напишите ответом.

Comment: жаль, но похоже это единственный из приемлемых выходов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

class MyDialog:

    def __init__(self, parent):

        top = self.top = Toplevel(parent)

        Label(top, text="\"**********************\"\n"
                          "Язык разработки:\tPython 3.6\n"
                          "Используемые модули и библиотеки:\n"
                          "- tkinter\n"
                          "- datetime\n"
                          "Дата выхода:\n"
                          "Version_1.1.0:\t 05. 2020\n"
                          "**********\n "
                          "**************",font='Arial 10').pack()

       
        b = Button(top, text="OK", command=self.ok)
        b.pack(pady=5)

    def ok(self):
        
        self.top.destroy()

def o_prog():
    root.update ()
    root.wait_window (d.top)

root = Tk()
d = MyDialog(root)
o_prog()
root.mainloop()
```

переделал под собственный диалог.